# How can I subtract two row's values within same column using a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need subtract values for two rows with same column. This is my query

```
SELECT TOP (10) [ID], [NAME], [VALUE] 
FROM [DATAINFO].[dbo].[DATA_INFO]
```

Example of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: Is there a photo to show what it should do, thanks

Comment: Have a look at `LAG`, e.g. `value- lag(value) over (order by id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2012 version of SQL Server or newer you could use:

```
select id, name, value,
       coalesce(value - lag(value) over (partition by (select null) order by id), 0) diff
from my_table
```

If `LAG` is not available, then use:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t1.value - t2.value, 0) diff
from my_table t1
left join my_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id + 1
```

`COALESCE` justmakes sure, that you get `0` when there's `null` (which means, there isn't previous row).

Comment: `partition by (select null)` shouldn't be needed here